# If $\Omega =\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $\mathcal G=\sigma (\{1\},\{2\},\{3,4\}\}$ can we know the cardinality of $\mathcal G$?

Tags: probability

If $\Omega =\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $\mathcal G=\sigma (\{1\},\{2\},\{3,4\})$ can we know the cardinality of $\mathcal G$ ? I tried to write $\mathcal G$ $$\{\Omega ,\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2,3,4\}, \{2\}, \{1,3,4\}, \{3,4\}\}$$
but how can I be sure that I didn't forget any event ?

Comment: What’s the definition of $\sigma$?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe : ?? Stable with complementary, and countable union (and $\Omega $ in the $\sigma -$algebra).

Comment: What about the complement of $\{3,4\}$?

Comment: If we *know* $\mathcal G$ then of course we also *know* its cardinality. Btw, if it is generated by a finite set then it will always be a power of $2$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2966461/75923) for that and you can use that here as a sanity check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually forgot $\{1,2\}$ which is the union of $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$. And that's it, easy to see that for every set in $\mathcal G$ its complement is also in $\mathcal G$ and that the union of any two sets in $\mathcal G$ is also in $\mathcal G$. You don't need to worry about infinite unions here because $\Omega$ is finite.

Comment: Nice see for $\{1,2\}$. So if $|A|=m$ and $A\subset 2^\Omega $ can I deduce that $|\sigma (A)|=2^{|A|}$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't here for a few hours so I saw this comment only now. Anyway, as I see Zvi already showed you a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

You can check that your answer is not correct because the number of elements of a finite $\sigma$-algebra is always a power of $2$.  Indeed, let $\sim$ be the equivalent relation in a countable (finite or infinite) set $\Omega$ relative to a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ on $\Omega$ defined by $a\sim b$ if and only if, any set $S\in \Sigma$ that contains $a$ also contains $b$.  Prove that $\sim$ is indeed an equivalent relation on $\Omega$.  Let $\Pi$ be the set of equivalence classes on $\Omega$ induced by $\sim$.  Define $f:\mathcal{P}(\Pi)\to \Sigma$ via $\mathcal{C}\mapsto \bigcup_{C\in\mathcal{C}}C$, where $\mathcal{P}(\Pi)$ is the power set of $\Pi$.  Show that $f$ is a bijection.  Hence, $|\Sigma|=\big|\mathcal{P}(\Pi)\big|=2^{|\Pi|}$.  In particular, if $\Omega$ is finite, $\Pi$ is finite and $|\Sigma|=2^{|\Pi|}$ is a power of $2$.  (Furthermore, this shows that there do not exist countably infinite $\sigma$-algebras.)

In your problem, you can see immediately that $\Pi=\big\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3,4\}\big\}$, so $\Sigma$ needs to have $2^3=8$ elements.  That is, $$\Sigma=\big\{\{\},\{1\},\{2\},\{3,4\},\{1,2\},\{1,3,4\},\{2,3,4\},\{1,2,3,4\}\big\}.$$

Comment: So if $|A|=m$ (and $A\subset 2^\Omega $), then always $|2^A|=2^{|A|}$ ? (I thought it was true only for $|A|=n$ of the form $1=\{a_1,...,a_n\}$).

Comment: Are you asking about this equality $\big|\mathcal{P}(A)\big|=2^{|A|}$?  If so, yes, the equality holds for any set $A$, and it works even if $A$ is infinite.

Comment: In fact about : if $A\subset \mathcal P(X)$ and $|A|=m$, does $|\sigma (A)|=2^{|A|}$ ?

Comment: @user601023  No.  Try $X=\{1,2,3\}$ and $A=\big\{\{1\},\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\big\}$.  The $\sigma$-algebra generated by $A$ has $2^3=8$ elements, but $2^{|A|}=2^4=16$.

Comment: Nice ! So, I guess that if all set in $A$ are disjoint, then it work, no ?

Comment: If the sets in $A$ are disjoint and the union is the whole $X$, then yes.  After all, $X$ has to be in the $\sigma$-algebra.